# GNOME shell periodically crashing

Tags: gnome, glibc, segmentation-fault

I'm on a laptop running Arch Linux. As of a series of updates applied this morning, I've had some issues with GNOME crashing, and being reloaded, forcing me to log in again -- and while my `tmux` sessions were still alive and well, all GUI applications had to be restarted after logging back in.

Checking `dmesg` consistently shows very similar errors coinciding with the crash times, which seem to occur at irregular intervals:

```
[ 7070.694904] gnome-shell[789]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f679a68fdec sp 00007fff1678a178 error 4 in libc-2.24.so[7f679a60c000+195000]
[10834.916178] perf: interrupt took too long (2527 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 78900
[17712.033332] perf: interrupt took too long (3162 > 3158), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63000
[18478.887765] gnome-shell[7900]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f4e0d19fdec sp 00007ffc94edda78 error 4 in libc-2.24.so[7f4e0d11c000+195000]
[26423.365242] perf: interrupt took too long (3987 > 3952), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50100
[32277.027055] gnome-shell[14894]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f56659a4dec sp 00007ffda63e4268 error 4 in libc-2.24.so[7f5665921000+195000]
```

All this tells me is that it's some issue with my `libc`, but I've *never* had to modify that, for as long as I've used Unix-based systems.

If I had to guess, GNOME itself is causing a segfault, but I haven't had any updates to GNOME or any directly related software in a while.

How can I diagnose this further? Is it possible to tell roughly what the issue is based on this information from `dmesg`?

What would a possible fix be?

Comment: I can confirm this behavior on my system too. I am running Fedora 25 and sometimes when I switch windows using Alt+Tab, the same thing happens to me too. I actually found your question here while searching for a known bug. Sorry that I can't help but did you already solve the issue?